# Nginx vhost file not working

Tags: nginx, vhosts

I have a super simple nginx vhost that should work. I've been researching this for hours and I am seriously at a loss, there's no reason this shouldn't work. I'm on 17.04 ubuntu and the latest nginx,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name utig.me;

    access_log /var/www/html/utig/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/utig/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/utig/public/;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

Anyone have a clue why this isn't working? I just get the default "Welcome to nginx" message.

Comment: `index` moves processing out of the `location` block where `root` isn't defined.

Comment: What does “not working” means? What do you do, what do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: I explained my issue, please read the whole question before replying. Anwyay, this is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name utig.me;

    root   /var/www/html/utig/public/;
    index index.html;

    access_log /var/www/html/utig/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/utig/logs/error.log;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. My other issue was I needed to make a symlink from sites-available to sites-enabled.